# Laravel Collection : Remove collection grouping after groupBy()

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

collect($vars)->groupBy() returns in the format

```
[
    'catgeory' => [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'type' => 'category'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name4', 'type' => 'category'],
    ]
    'name' => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name2', 'type' => 'name'],
    'value' => ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'name3', 'type' => 'value']
]
```

What is the best way to change to like this, removing
 the grouping but preferrably using the collections itself

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'type' => 'category'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name4', 'type' => 'category'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name2', 'type' => 'name'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'name3', 'type' => 'value'],
]
```

Original array is this:

```
[
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name2', 'type' => 'name'],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1', 'type' => 'category'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name4', 'type' => 'category'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'name3', 'type' => 'value'],
]
```

Comment: share your original array, value of `$vars` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-flatten) with a depth of one.

```
collect($vars)->groupBy('type')->flatten(1);
```